# PHPMyAdmin sql query ERROR 1064

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am trying to run a query script to create a table for banners

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tan_banners` (
`id` smallint(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`banner_tag` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT ”,
`descr` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT ”,
`code` text NOT NULL,
`approve` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ’0′,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

But I keep getting:

```
error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '”, `descr` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT ”, `code` text NOT NULL, `approv' at line 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You have extra odd quotes in the query on the `banner_tag`, `descr` & `approve` commands:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tan_banners` (
`id` smallint(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`banner_tag` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT ”,
`descr` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT ”,
`code` text NOT NULL,
`approve` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ’0′,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tan_banners` (
`id` smallint(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`banner_tag` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`descr` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`code` text NOT NULL,
`approve` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```